# Static Files not Displayed after Deployment to Google Cloud Run

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, wagtail, google-cloud-run

I have a wagtail web application, It works perfectly in localhost but in production, the Debug is set to False and all the static files are not displayed in the deployed website, I am attaching the Dockerfile code below:

```
    # Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.7
LABEL maintainer="hello@wagtail.io"

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_ENV production

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /code/
COPY . /code/
# Set the working directory to /code/
WORKDIR /code/

RUN python manage.py migrate

RUN useradd wagtail
RUN chown -R wagtail /code
USER wagtail

EXPOSE 8000
CMD exec gunicorn myweb_blog.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --workers 3
```

The Production.py settings file is given below:

```
    from .base import *


SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER=True

FEATURE_POLICY = {
    'geolocation': 'none',

    
    }

#CSP_BLOCK_ALL_MIXED_CONTENT=True
#

        


SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF=True
SECURE_FRAME_DENY=True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS=2592000
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS=True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD=True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY='same-origin'


SECRET_KEY = 'A Secure Secret'
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my domain'] 
DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

--Base.py--

```
"""
Django settings for myweb_blog project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'search',
    'blog',
    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',

    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]



ROOT_URLCONF = 'myweb_blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]







WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myweb_blog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    #Database details is filled here
}







# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
]

# ManifestStaticFilesStorage is recommended in production, to prevent outdated
# Javascript / CSS assets being served from cache (e.g. after a Wagtail upgrade).
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


# Wagtail settings

WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = "myweb_blog"

# Base URL to use when referring to full URLs within the Wagtail admin backend -
# e.g. in notification emails. Don't include '/admin' or a trailing slash
BASE_URL = 'my domain'
```

Please Help me with a solution to get my website up and running. Thanks a Lot

--Update--

The problem is Solved Thanks after properly following the cloud run docs and White Noise(http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Django is not built to serve static and media files in production [Deploying Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Since you're already on Google Cloud Run, a simple fix to your problem is to serve static files from a Google Cloud option like [Cloud Storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files)

Optionally, you could set up a free account on AWS (Amazon Web Services) and utilize the S3 buckets which I've found to be much easier.

Here is a quick reference guide to [Serving Django Media Files on AWS](https://medium.com/swlh/serve-django-static-and-media-files-in-production-348fe6c7781d)

Comment: Using Cloud Storage Buckets Works Flawlessly! also it seems to be the recommended method for serving the static files as per the latest video on google cloud platform channel in youtube [ https://youtu.be/9kfIvlMi798 ] on hosting django website in cloud run. And By the Way thanks for the Suggestion, but I am now well adjusted with Google Cloud Platform and have developed familiarity with it, but still Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [Whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) for static files.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/django-demo-app-unicodex is an excellent starting point for running Django (and therefore Wagtail) on Google Cloud Run. It includes a [section on configuring Cloud Storage Buckets](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/django-demo-app-unicodex/blob/master/docs/30-setup-bucket.md).

Comment: tomd Thanks a lot for the help. I am able to get it running. Thanks once again.

Comment: @ManavSengupta were you able to get Whitenoise to compress and serve your static content using Cloud Run? I tried this with App Engine but wasn't successful.

Comment: @franciscojavierarceo I asked the above question for Cloud Run, but I am using App engine for a long time and whitenoise is not required , there is a simple(and recommended) fix just add : handlers: - url: /static static_dir: static/ in your app.yaml   .   My app.yaml looks like : https://ibb.co/87CjcR1